# Issue with New Xamarin.Forms Flyout menu

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am creating a Xamarin forms application and I was using Xamarin forms new Shell template. I have created a fly out menu and in the menu i have a Home page (which has a listview) and secondary page.

When adding new items to the home page it seems that the overide Onappearing() method is not working. unless you open the flyout menu and open another page then come back to the home page. Then you will see the updated list items in the listview.

With out the flyout menu the list page works fine.

I tried Shell.Current.Navigation.PopModalAsync();

// This is the main page

```
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        await _connection.CreateTableAsync<WorkOutModel>();
        var workOutsList = await _connection.Table<WorkOutModel>().ToListAsync();
        _workOuts = new ObservableCollection<WorkOutModel>(workOutsList.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ToList());
        MyWorkOutList.ItemsSource = _workOuts;

        base.OnAppearing();
    }
    async void Create_WorkOut_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (await DisplayAlert("Warning!!", "Are you sure you want to create a new workout calendar? Current calendar will be deleted.", "Yes", "No"))
        {
            await _connection.DropTableAsync<WorkOutModel>();
            await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new CreateWorkOutCalendar());

        }
    }
```

// Page that you get sent to to add items to the list

async void Save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

var datePicked = startDate.Date;

```
        try
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < workOutList.Count; i++)
            {
                WorkOutModel itemsList = new WorkOutModel()
                {
                    Title = selectedProgram,
                    WorkOutTitle = workOutList[i],
                    Date = datePicked.AddDays(i),
                    Notes = "",
                    Done = false

                };
                await _connection.InsertAsync(itemsList);
                _workOuts.Add(itemsList);
            }

            await DisplayAlert("Calendar Created", $"{selectedProgram} WorkOut Calendar has been created.", "Great!");
            await Navigation.PopModalAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            await DisplayAlert("Error", "Something went wrong! please try again", "OK");
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you update the add the new items to `ObservableCollection`, do you clear the all the items in `ObservableCollection`, then re-add the new items to  `ObservableCollection` like this code   Items.Clear();
                var items = await DataStore.GetItemsAsync(true);
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    Items.Add(item);
                }

Comment: Beacuse I only want one table at a time.. I drop the table and recreate it.. from what I can tell the onAppering is not being called after the Navigation.PopModalAsync() is executed. I know this because if I switch pages and come back the listview shows up with the updated list. Maybe it has something to do with Shell?

Comment: `OnAppearing` method could be executed that this page disppaered, then immediately prior to the Page becoming visible, so if you did not open another page then come back to the home page, this method cannot be executed.

Comment: That's the thing.. I'm pushing to a new page. Once I'm done on the new page I pop that page off the stack and it goes back to the main page and it looks like it doesn't recall the onAppering method..

Comment: I put a `DisplayAlert` in `OnAppearing` method, I get this result like this GIF https://imgur.com/a/rAoz6nq, it could be executed, you can download this demo, and test it, If this demo could be running normally.https://github.com/851265601/shellOnAppear